# Can I display the Google Account Picker in an IFrame like medium?

Tags: iframe, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, x-frame-options

My company has its login tied to Google and when users go here - http://api.radiumcrm.com/sessions/new we show them the Google Account Picker page.

[image]

I'm trying to allow users to select their account and login through an IFRAME via our company's chrome extension. When I try this URL in an IFRAME I get this error -

`Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?service=lso&continue=https%3A%2F…57%26from_login%3D1%26hl%3Den%26as%3D-7f65cece530df7dd&btmpl=authsub&hl=en' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.`

I know Google probably does this for security reasons but is there any good workaround for this?

Answer (score 4):

For good reasons you shouldn't be iframing the Google login page. What is the reason you need to do this? Can do the same in a popup?
Also have you looked at 
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/get-google-api-clientid.
For window you should add
data-auto_select="true" https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/automatic-sign-in-sign-out.